# DisplayPort to HDMI (PC->TV)

Tags: hdmi, tv, displayport, mirroring

I would like to mirror my PC monitor to TV. I have a cable with two types of ports. The PC side is DisplayPort and TV side is HDMI. After first connecting it was successfully mirrored, but after reconnecting it is not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried shutting off your monitor first, before running it to the TV? Sometimes this solves the problem. Or shut off the computer and then run the cords.

Comment: not working, too :/

Comment: You do have the HDMI on the TV side correct?

Comment: You might try want to try a page which has mulitple solutions for a DIY "How to Troubleshoot HDMI Connection Problems" LiveWire is a pretty good site https://www.lifewire.com/fix-hdmi-connection-problems-1846811

Comment: The only way I know to do this is have it set as the _default_ monitor. I'm glad you have worked it out. Peace. : -)

Comment: You should post an Answer saying how you solved the problem. It may help a whole slew of people out there with the same problem. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: The only problem is that when you switch off the TV, DisplayPort in PC gets deactivated and is then switched off. That means, tha if you wanna mirror that on the TV, after every time you switch on TV, you have to put in DisplayPort......Everytime :/ :/

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that when you switch off the TV, DisplayPort in PC gets deactivated and is then switched off. That means, tha if you wanna mirror that on the TV, after every time you switch on TV, you have to put in DisplayPort......Everytime :/ :/

Comment: This is likely because the stops reporting the port as available when the TV is off, so your computer thinks it has been completely disconnected. Probably a byproduct of using a TV as a monitor instead of an actual monitor.